# CodenameOne ComboBox NumberFormatException

Tags: java, codenameone

This code

```
ComboBox<Map<String, Object>> combo = new ComboBox<> (
createListEntry("A Game of Thrones", "1996"),
createListEntry("A Clash Of Kings", "1998"),
createListEntry("A Storm Of Swords", "2000"),
createListEntry("A Feast For Crows", "2005"),
createListEntry("A Dance With Dragons", "2011"),
createListEntry("The Winds of Winter", "2016 (please, please, please)"),
createListEntry("A Dream of Spring", "Ugh"));

combo.setRenderer(new GenericListCellRenderer<>(new MultiButton(), new MultiButton()));
conPaid.addComponent(combo);
```

is throwing NumberFormatException

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "true"
>   at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>   [EDT] 0:0:14,365 - Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException - For input string: "true"
>     at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt([EDT] 0:0:14,365 - Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException >- For input string: "true"
>   Integer.java:770)
>     at com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager.getThemeConstant(UIManager.java:1259)
>     at com.codename1.ui.List.initLaf(List.java:313)
>     at com.codename1.ui.Component.(Component.java:692)
>     at com.codename1.ui.List.(List.java:301)
>     at com.codename1.ui.ComboBox.(ComboBox.java:150)
>     at com.codename1.ui.ComboBox.(ComboBox.java:134)
>     at >net.chibex.ozioma.gui.widget.NewsletterListInfoContainer.fillComponents(NewsletterListInfoContainer.java:116)
>     at net.chibex.ozioma.gui.widget.NewsletterListInfoContainer.(NewsletterListInfoContainer.java:42)
>     at net.chibex.ozioma.gui.NewsletterListInfoForm.beforeShow(NewsletterListInfoForm.java:66)
>     at net.chibex.ozioma.gui.NewsletterListInfoForm.show(NewsletterListInfoForm.java:42)
>     at >net.chibex.ozioma.gui.widget.HomePhoneLayoutContainer.lambda$addContent$2(HomePhoneLayoutContainer.java:329)
>     at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:349)
>     at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:579)
>     at com.codename1.components.FloatingActionButton.fireActionEvent(FloatingActionButton.java:327)
>     at com.codename1.ui.Button.released(Button.java:613)
>     at com.codename1.components.FloatingActionButton.released(FloatingActionButton.java:334)
>     at com.codename1.ui.Button.pointerReleased(Button.java:712)
>     at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:3590)
>     at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.pointerReleased(Dialog.java:1769)
>     at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:4679)
>     at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2289)
>     at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1214)
>     at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1393)
>     at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1432)
>     at com.codename1.ui.Form.showModal(Form.java:2358)
>     at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.showModal(Dialog.java:1138)
>     at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:582)

Comment: Did you define a theme constant to true in the CSS?

Comment: The example https://gist.github.com/codenameone/7aa88182d6a7f63cbd4e#file-comboboxsample-java, from which the code of the question is taken from, works correctly in the Simulator.

Comment: @Shai Almog, I set the theme constant includeNativeBool to true

Comment: @Francesco Galgani, the exception shows on Simulator but the ComboBox components still display well.

Comment: It looks like `listItemGapInt` is set to `true` instead of an integer value. How did you generate the res file? Did you use css or something else?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog, ``listItemGapInt`` was the issue. I used css to generate res file. Have corrected the mistake. Thanks the guide.

Comment: Maybe you should file an RFE so CSS validates theme constants. So if a value ends with Int it should verify it's numeric. If it ends with Bool it should verify it's boolean etc...